# Javascript private variable param update

Tags: javascript

**Resume of the question: how to save internally the params of a function call so it can be use in the next call**

I know my problem is not that complicated but I'm kinda confused here.
Here is the problem:

Updateorderbook is a function that connect to a websocket, subscribing to a channel. This function needs to unsubscribe the current channel when it's called for the second time (or more) before to connect to the new channel.
To unsubscribe I need the "previousparams", so what I tried to do is to stock those params in this.currentParams but obviously it's not working.

To resume my problem I need to save internally the params of the call so i can access it on the next call.

```
updateOrderbook: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    var ws = OrderbookSocket.getInstance();

    if(ws.readyState === 1) {
        var request = OrderbookRequest.request(this.currentParams, 'unsubscribe');
        ws.send(request);
        // this.currentParams = params;
    }

    ws.onopen = function(e) {
        var request = OrderbookRequest.request(params,'subscribe');
        self.currentParams = params;

        ws.send(request);
    }
    ws.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log(" WS has been closed: ",e);
    }

    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    }
}
```

What I don't udnerstand is taht this.currentParams is automatically updated even is ws.onopen is not called! (it's like binded there is something I don't get here).

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: I want this.currentparams to be the params of the last call, not the current call

Comment: The question is how to save internally the params of a call so it can be use in the next one

Comment: I'm not sure if by internally you mean in your js-code or in the function, if you mean the first one, you can just specify the variable outside the function

Comment: What is *this*? It's set by the call, you haven't shown that. Typically  such parameters are stored in a closure.

Comment: I want that when I call this function I always have the parameters of the previous call available

Comment: I think the concept you're looking for is called *memoization*.

Comment: Not really pawel. All I want is unsubscribe the previous channel so I need the previous params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that variables are passed by valu and objects by reference, so you need to clone your object, using _.clone() underscore function for example

If this is the Only Thing you want, you can just Change your code to:

```
var gl_params;
updateOrderbook: function(params) {
    // gl_params still your old params
    // params are your new params
    var self = this;
    var ws = OrderbookSocket.getInstance();
    if(ws.readyState === 1) {
        var request = OrderbookRequest.request(gl_params, 'unsubscribe');
        ws.send(request);
    }
    ws.onopen = function(e) {
        var request = OrderbookRequest.request(params,'subscribe');
        gl_params = _.clone(params); 
        ws.send(request);
    }
    ws.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log(" WS has been closed: ",e);
    }
    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: So here you meant this.currentParams should be gl_params ?

Comment: exactly and gl_params is outsite of your function.. (globally declared)
- Thanks for correcting

Comment: well it's not working, OrderbookRequest.request(gl_params, 'unsubscribe');
is still sending the newparams I don't get it. I've tried what you suggested before ,,,, azdjazi reallly annoying I'pm sure it's easy

Comment: gl_params for 'subscribe' shoudl be params (since this are the new params). But this is a detail the real problem is that it's not working, gl_params for 'unsubscribe' are still equal to 'params' (the new one). I guess this is because this code is asynchronous

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, now unsubscribe Contains the old params from the last Ajax call, than if onclose the gl_params get set to the new params. if you now call the subscribe than the gl_params get set to newly added params

Comment: unfortunately it's not related to ws.onclose, the websocket is never closed, just subscribe and unsubscribe command sent

Comment: but I think you can solve it using this concept, no?

Comment: Yes but it was not really the issue. I found finally the problem. It's because Variables are passed by value, objects by reference !! O_O I knew it was dumb. Let me update your answer I'll validate it then, appreciate your efforts